# Matter of suffix for naive bayes

Tags: algorithm, naivebayes

I'm trying to implement naive bayes for personal purpose and can't determine the significance of suffix for the specific words. For example: does it matter to use all form of word "virus" (virus, viruses, virusing) or I can count `^virus*` regex trying to catch semantic load?